# get file input values from array - PHP

Tags: php, forms, file, input, upload

I have a block of PHP which sits onto a form I have where I have multiple file input form elements allowing the form user to upload files. This works well, but I want to be able to return the filename / path of the server for where the file has been uploaded - but cant seem to work out how to do this - currently the value of the field comes back as "array".

Any ideas on how to get the actual uploaded path and filename for each input?

```
// initialize output;
$output = true;

// valid extensions
$ext_array = array('pdf', 'txt', 'doc', 'docx', 'rtf', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'eps', 'svg', 'gif', 'ai');

// create unique path for this form submission
//$uploadpath = 'assets/uploads/';

// you can create some logic to automatically
// generate some type of folder structure here.
// the path that you specify will automatically
// be created by the script if it doesn't already
// exist.

// UPLOAD TO FOLDER IN /ASSETS/UPLOADS/ WITH ID OF THE PARENT PROJECT FOLDER RESOURCE 

// Get page ID
// $pageid = $modx->resource->get('id');
// $uploadpath = 'assets/uploads/'.$pageid.'/';

// Get parent page title
$parentObj = $modx->resource->getOne('Parent');
$parentpageid = $parentObj->get('pagetitle');
$uploadpath = 'assets/uploads/'.$parentpageid.'/';

// get full path to unique folder
$target_path = $modx->config['base_path'] . $uploadpath;

// get uploaded file names:
$submittedfiles = array_keys($_FILES);


// loop through files
foreach ($submittedfiles as $sf) {

// Get Filename and make sure its good.
$filename = basename( $_FILES[$sf]['name'] );

// Get file's extension
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$ext = mb_strtolower($ext); // case insensitive

// is the file name empty (no file uploaded)
if($filename != '') {

    // is this the right type of file?
    if(in_array($ext, $ext_array)) {

        // clean up file name and make unique
        $filename = mb_strtolower($filename); // to lowercase
        $filename = str_replace(' ', '_', $filename); // spaces to underscores
        $filename = date("Y-m-d_G-i-s_") . $filename; // add date & time

        // full path to new file
        $myTarget = $target_path . $filename;

        // create directory to move file into if it doesn't exist
        mkdir($target_path, 0755, true);

        // is the file moved to the proper folder successfully?
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$sf]['tmp_name'], $myTarget)) {
            // set a new placeholder with the new full path (if you need it in subsequent hooks)
            $modx->setPlaceholder('fi.'.$sf.'_new', $myTarget);
            // set the permissions on the file
            if (!chmod($myTarget, 0644)) { /*some debug function*/ }

        } else {
            // File not uploaded
            $errorMsg = 'There was a problem uploading the file.';
            $hook->addError($sf, $errorMsg);
            $output = false; // generate submission error
        }

    } else {
        // File type not allowed
        $errorMsg = 'Type of file not allowed.';
        $hook->addError($sf, $errorMsg);
        $output = false; // generate submission error
    }

// if no file, don't error, but return blank
} else {
    $hook->setValue($sf, '');
}

}

return $output;
```

Comment: what about $myTarget?

Comment: @dubbs - You can make session to the "action" page and use $myTarget.

Comment: Thanks guys - when I return the value of $myTarget I get the file input field names - not the files uploaded..

Comment: Sorry - it does return it actually - needed it just below the " $myTarget = $target_path . $filename;" line of code // thanks

Comment: But it returns just the last file uploaded, can I get ideally each file uploaded individually, or if not - the group of files uploaded?

Comment: I am using a session variable to get the value of $myTarget - but it just returns the last of the files uploaded - how do I get each file?

Comment: Could I adapt this code to make it specific to each file input I have in the form - that might make it easier?